# how to update Android app in background service with no history(empty stack)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have an Android application(3rd party, not in google play) which checks for newer version once a day. The process of checking for newer version and downloading it, took place in a `Service`. Because i didn't want to halt user(specially when Internet has a low speed) from navigating/using other part of application, i used a service.

I implement a `BroadcastReceiver` to be notified when download completes(`ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`). I want to install new version by starting its activity with an empty stack. I do as follows:

```
installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(installIntent);
```

but i got this error in log:

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

and starting intent with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag, won't clear the activities stack.

**Notice**: if user click on back button or cancel, navigates to activity of my app but in such case i wanted app to close without "not responding" message.

**Question**: Is it possible to run activity(installer one) with empty activity stack in a service? Is there any other way to do this work? If yes how?

By the way, my intention from all these is to force user to install updates.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your manifest. I assume that the installer `Activity` is not the usual root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER.

Comment: Installer Activity isn't defined in `Manifest`. it is called via intent: `Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myFile),
                                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");`

Comment: Project is in [this link](https://github.com/Kickass86/MPAS/tree/master/app/src/main) if you need something else.

Comment: OK, you are launching the Android installer. I don't understand what you mean by "run installer with empty activity stack in a service". What is the problem that you are having? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: i want application to terminate(not with "not responding" message) and just installer do its work to install newer version. i couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here is one example:

Create an "installer" `Activity`, which just launches the Android installer and then calls `finish()` in `onCreate()`.

From your `BroadcastReceiver` you can cause your application to exit and launch the installer by doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyInstallerActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear any activities in your application that may be running and run `MyInstallerActivity`. In `MyInstallerActivity.onCreate()` you should just launch the Android installer (as you are already doing) and call `finish()`. If the user cancels the installation, your app will no longer be running.